# Java interface without type specified

Tags: java, interface

I have a question regarding interface design. I will try to illustrate with a simple example below.

Imagine i have an interface:

```
public interface TestInterface {

    public List getData();

}
```

And i have an implementing class:

```
public class TestInterfaceImpl implements TestInterface{

    public List<Customer> getData() {
        return null; //will return a list of customers
    } 
}
```

I this bad design to return a List in the interface without a type specified (List) and then specifying it in the implementing class (List)?

Thanks - any comment is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's pretty much a bad idea to use [raw types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) in any new code. Instead, [parameterize the interface.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

```
public interface TestInterface<T> {

    public List<T> getData();

}

public class TestInterfaceImpl implements TestInterface<Customer> {

    public List<Customer> getData() {
        return null; //will return a list of customers
    } 
}
```

If you've never written a generic class before, or just aren't sure about all the details, you might find [the Java Tutorial's Generics Lesson](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) useful.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use parametrized iface:

```
public interface TestInterface<T> {

    public List<T> getData();

}

public class TestInterfaceImpl implements TestInterface<Customer> {

    public List<Customer> getData() {
        return null; //will return a list of customers
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's not bad design per se, but **generics** is better, type-safe design:

```
//parametrize your interface with a general type T
public interface TestInterface<T> {
    public List<T> getData();
}

//pass a real type to an interface
public class TestInterfaceImpl implements TestInterface<Customer> {
    public List<Customer> getData() {
        return null; 
    } 
}
```